Kendo UI grid showing no records found when reloading it's previous grid state using setOptions
Our project has a Kendo grid where the grid databound event saves the grid state for a particular user at any give time when user applies filter or makes any changes to grid view.
Kendo grid structure is loaded in MVC as follows:
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Entity>()
          .Name("FeedGrid")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "FeedGrid" })
          .Sortable(sortable => sortable
              .AllowUnsort(true)
              .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
          .Scrollable()
          .ColumnMenu()
          .Filterable()
          .Reorderable(ro => ro.Columns(true))
          .Resizable(rs => rs.Columns(true))
          .Groupable()
          .NoRecords("<b style='text-align:center'><i>---- No records found ----</i></b>")
          .Columns(columns =>...)
          .Events(events =>
                     { events.ExcelExport("exportGridWithTemplatesContent");
    events.ColumnShow("SaveGridState");
    events.ColumnHide("SaveGridState");
    events.ColumnReorder("SaveGridState");
    events.ColumnResize("SaveGridState");
    events.ColumnMenuInit("SortFilterDropdown");
    events.DataBound("SaveGridState")};
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .ServerOperation(false)));

The data to the above grid is passed in javascript/jquery as follows along with retrieving the saved grid state:
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            $.ajax({
                url: GetApiUrl('Api/GetGrid'),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(DataSourceRequestViewModel(options, currentSearchXml)),
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    options.error(result);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total"
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#FeedGrid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource);
    $("#FeedGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}, 100);



var stateGrid = GetGridState("FeedGrid");
var grid = $("#FeedGrid").getKendoGrid();
stateGrid.toolbar = [{ template: kendo.template($('#FeedGrid').find(".k-grid-toolbar").html()) }];
 
if (!isNullOrEmpty(stateGrid)) {
   grid.setOptions(stateGrid);
}

Though the datasource is making the ajax call and receiving the right response, the data is not being rendered on grid in UI. It shows No records found. When I remove the setOptions it loads the data correctly. But the setoptions is an important feature and we need it, Please help me here. This looks like a bug from kendo.
I tried the following solution to wait for the grid to load completely and then use setoptions but that is loading the grid twice and is not user friendly.
Tried solution:
function getFeedGridSettings(id) {
    var isLoading = $('.k-loading-text').length;
    if (isLoading) {
        if (stateGrid == undefined) {
            stateGrid = GetGridState(id);
            stateGrid.toolbar = [{ template: kendo.template($('#' + id).find(".k-grid-toolbar").html()) }];
        }
        setTimeout(function () { getFeedGridSettings('FeedGrid'); }, 10000);
    }
    else {
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(stateGrid)) {
            var grid = $("#" + id).getKendoGrid();
            grid.setOptions(stateGrid);
        }
    }
}

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            $.ajax({
                url: GetApiUrl('Api/GetGrid'),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(DataSourceRequestViewModel(options, searchXml)),
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    options.error(result);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total"
    }
});
setTimeout(function () { $("#FeedGrid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource) }, 100);
getFeedGridSettings('FeedGrid'); 

Please help me in finding the right solution.
